# Two date calculations across two years

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to calculate the number of months in two different years for a small financial report that gives a total for each month, a YTD and AVG.  For example let's say a client joined us in April of last year so last year they would have 9 months of charges and this year 11. For this particular piece of the report this is for adjustments made on those charges.  Not all months would have adjustments but all the months (9 and 11) would have charges.

[image]

With this example these are the adjustments for each month.  I can get a min transaction date of April 2014 to help me calculate the AVG for 2014.  Above is not correct.  That is YTD/3, not YTD/9 as it should be.  But this I can calculate but I can't get it to work for 2015, YTD/11.

What I have right now (simplified version)

```
declare @StartDate DATETIME = getdate()
, @MinDate DATETIME

select @MinDate = min(txndate)
from dbo.txn

select d.year,
      d.jan,
      d.feb,
      etc...
      d.YTD/--how to calculate here??
from ....
```

I can't seem to put together a case statement regarding the different years and the calculation.  Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #txn
(
year smallint,
Jan money, Feb money, Mar money, Apr money,
May money, Jun money, Jul money, Aug money,
Sep money, Oct money, Nov money, Dec money
)

insert #txn
values(2014,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,95,36.89,95), 
(2015,100,6389.27,null,null,1035,257,669.05,0,null,514,2791.01,null)


select year, month, money
from #txn
unpivot
(
    money
    for month in (Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec)
) unpivotalias

;with aggregate as
(
select year, sum(money) as 'YTD', sum(money)/count(*) as 'AVG'
from #txn
unpivot
(
    money
    for month in (Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec)
) unpivotalias
group by year
)
select t.year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,YTD,AVG  
from #txn as t join aggregate as a on t.year = a.year
order by t.year
```